# Passed data with URLSearchParams is something other in PHP backend

Tags: php, axios

I'm trying to create async validation with call to backend. I need to pass data using `let params = new URLSearchParams(); params.append('email', registerEmail);` because in other way PHP doesn't see `$_POST[email]`.

`registerEmail` which I append to params is `123@123.pl`.

```
    let params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('email', registerEmail);

    return axios.post('/api/auth/checkUnique.php', params, axiosConfig)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('true');
            console.log(res);
            return true;
        })
        .catch(res => {
            console.log('false');
            console.log(res);
            return false;
        });
```

On backend I'm doing select do db with this value and `var_dump()` it before.

```
var_dump('email is: ');
var_dump($_POST['email']);

$query = "
    SELECT 
      * 
    FROM 
      " . $this->table_name . " 
    WHERE 
      nick = ?
    OR
      email = ?
  ";

// prepare query statement
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare($query);

// bind params
$stmt->bindParam(1, $nick);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $email);

// execute query
$stmt->execute();

//count if there is any
$num = $stmt->rowCount();

if ($num > 0)
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return true;
}
```

And although I'm sure that in my db I have one email `123@123.pl` it can't find it and it's returning true.

`var_dump()` function in first lines is returning `data: "string(10) \"email is: \"\nstring(25) \"[object HTMLInputElement]\"\n"`. I think it is not exacly `123@123.pl` as I want to and that is why my `SELECT` can't find any records.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you say it returning `object HTMLInputElement`, 
and that is not good.

`return axios.post('/api/auth/checkUnique.php', params, axiosConfig)`

PHP expect to get `<input name='email'>` or like in this example `params` must be type `json`

`{email: some@email.com}`

And there is your problem.

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: just try to pass json `{email: "some@email,com"}` instead `params` or what is `registerEmail`? Can you do `console.log(registerEmail)`

Comment: Well when I `console.log(registerEmail)` I found out that it is not value from input it is entire input instead `<input id="registerEmail" class="form-control" data-v-55be22a9="" placeholder="email@example.com" required="required" type="email">`

Comment: So you need something like this
`var emailInput = registerEmail.val(); var params = {email: emailInput}`

Comment: Yes I end with using registerEmail.value just like that.